# PHP POST requests timeout

Tags: php, file-upload, timeout, http-post, request-timed-out

I'm currently working on a upload script supporting *larger* uploads (~50 Mb) and I have very rapidly run into a problem! I'm using the traditional POST request with a form uploading the file to a temp location and later moving it with PHP. Naturally I've updated my php.ini file to support slightly larger than default files and files around 15 Mb upload really well!

The main problem is due to my hosting company. They let scripts *timeout* after 60 seconds meaning that POST requests taking longer than 60 seconds to complete will die before the temp file reaches the PHP script and this naturally yields an internal server error.

Not being able to crank the timeout on the server (after heated debates) I'm considering the options. Is there a way to *bump* the request or somehow refresh it to notify the server and reset the timing? Or are there alternative upload methods that don't timeout?

Comment: I wasn't aware that POST submit was timed and part of a script timout, I've never run into this issue, and have had uploads in excess of 300mb (private applications).

Comment: With PHP, any upload-related settings HAVE to be done via php.ini-level settings (or overrides in httpd.conf/.htaccess). They cannot be changed via ini_set, as the upload has to complete BEFORE PHP will start executing your code to reach those settings. Short of chunking your uploads using a client-side flash/java-based uploader, there's nothing you do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With great difficulty. By far your easiest option is to dump the hard-headed host and pick one that actually lets you be productive. I personally use [TSOHost](http://tsohost.co.uk/) - been with them for over a year and a half and have so far had absolutely no reason to complain (not even a slight annoyance).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could consider. Each has a cost, and you'll need to determine which one is least costly.

1. Get a new hosting company. This may be your best solution.
2. Design a rather complex client-side system that breaks up the upload into multiple chunks and submits them via AJAX. This is ugly especially since it is only useful in getting around a host rule.

I'd really research #1.

Comment: I guess thats what you get for selecting a cheap hosting solution :P Thanks for the super fast replys :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you really sure it s a timeout issue? My first idea...

- the transfert failed due to a configuration limitation set up in the web server php.ini file. You need to change it or set it as local settings in your script

  # find it in php.ini used by your configuration
  memory_limit = 96M
  post_max_size = 64M 
  upload_max_filesize = 64M

Or directly inyour script

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '96M'); 
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M'); 
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```